# Running C++ with Eclipse on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

So I'm running Mac OSX Lion and I recently installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. I recently started programming in C++ and I wanted to be able to use Eclipse as my main IDE. So first thing I did was install the Command Line told from Xcode in order to be able to use the g++ compiler. I then went into eclipse -> help -> install new software and entered the following link: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo .

I installed all of the Main Features and the Optional Features. I then created a new C++ Hello World Project and built it. However when I right click on the binary file, there in no "Run as local C/C++ Application" option. There's actually no run option at all.

I downloaded and installed the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers and created a new hello world project just to test. This one seemed to work fine. Why does it work in the c/c++ IDE but not in the java IDE with the CDT installed along-side?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. But I'd suggested staying the hell away from Eclipse for C++. It's great for Java, but my experience for C++ is that it is a total PITA. If you have XCode, give that a shot, it's not bad. Personally I settled on using VIM. Ok, here come the downvotes :).

Comment: The more I keep fighting with Eclipse, the more I'm inclined to agree. I have nothing against Xcode, I just figured since I was already using Eclipse for Java, then I might as well try it for other languages. Unfortunately, Eclipse is far from being easy to use even for an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of toying around, I came up with a somewhat annoying solution. Because it worked with the C/C++ IDE, I just decided to look at everything that was installed in that version and make sure it was installed in the Java IDE. For some odd reason it worked. I add already installed all the main features but I guess it wasn't enough.

Comment: So there were still some essential C++ plug-ins or features needed to run C++ code, when trying to use the Eclipse base Java IDE with CDT added?

Answer (score 0):

What is the view name - is it "Package Explorer" or "Project Explorer"? The first one is explicitly for Java and does not support some C++ tooling features. Switch to C/C++ perspective and try again.